# Probablity of being correct x times in ESP trainer

Tags: probability

My statistics knowledge is a little rusty, so I will be happy for any help.

For fun I've downloaded the app ESP trainer.

It shows you 4 colors, of which you must choose the correct one (which has been chosen randomly by the app). If you choose a wrong one, it will continue to the next question with a new correct color (so, only 1 guess per question).

It shows you 24 consecutive questions, and the correct answers are of course assumed to be independent of each other.

What is the probability of getting 11 answers correct out of 24 questions?

Or even better, what is the probability of getting x answers out of 24 questions correct?

Comment: So as I interpret it, the probability of getting a single trial correct is $p=\frac{1}{4}$. Now you have 24 Bernoulli trials ... Are you familiar with the binomial distribution?

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks Matti, interpretation correct. Bernouilli rings a faint bell. But from online Bernouilli calculators I get that P(X >= 11) = 0.0213, taking the reciproke value I guess that means that 11 or more correct answers should happen in 1 out of around 47 trials (?). However it would take a bit of time to calculate it myself. Thanks for hint, answer if you like points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $X=$ the number of correct answers (when solving problems with the binomial distribution, the word choice is often "successes"), then $X$ follows the binomial distribution with parameter value $p=\frac{1}{4}$. The probabilities are relatively easy to calculate. For example, the probability that there are exactly $11$ successes is
$$
P(X = 11) = {24 \choose 11} \left(\frac{1}{4} \right)^{11} \left(\frac{3}{4} \right)^{24-11} \approx 0.014~139
$$
Or about $1.4~\%$. On the other hand, the probability of **at least 11** successes, is
$$
\begin{split}
P(X \geq 11) &= P(X = 11) + P(X = 12) + \ldots + P(X = 24)\\
&=
 \sum_{k=11}^{24} {24 \choose k} \left(\frac{1}{4} \right)^k \left(\frac{3}{4} \right)^{24-k}\\
&\approx 0.021~338 
\end{split}
$$

PS. I don't recommend thinking in terms of "1 out of 47 trials", because then we're mixing up two different notions of a "trial" in this context. So just stick to thinking "about two per cent".

Comment: Excellent, thanks